# htaccess | How would I allow a '.' in an API URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am creating a API for a project of mine. The problem I face is using a period in my API url. When I have the period in my URL, it redirects to a `Error 404` page. However, when I remove the period, it works perfectly fine. I will provide my .htaccess code below. How would I make it so I can use a period in the URL?

`https://example.com/api/update/1.0` <-

**htaccess file**

```
RewriteRule ^update/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]*)$ update.php?version=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This actually is not a question about .htaccess or rewriting, but about basic knowledge of "regular expression". You want to read about that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Try this regex this will catch a version like `1.0.2` also.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteRule ^update/([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.{1,})?([0-9]+)?/? update.php?version=$1$2$3  [NC,L]
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with that code, when I tried this URL -> `https://example.com/api/update/1.0` it went completely bonkers and redirected me to `var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api/update.php?version=1.0` What is going on?

Comment: @PhoenixCMS, looks like your actual uri starts after `api` in link, I edited my solution now could you please check it once?

Comment: It works if I use `1.0.0`, is their a way to have it accept `1.0` and `1.0.0` format?

Comment: @PhoenixCMS, sure, please try my updated regex and let me know? This should handle both `1.0` and `1.0.2` too.

Comment: I have added it to my htaccess.